# Why whitespace isn't include in vim backreference wrapped content?

Tags: vim

I got some code with the format looks like: `print 'hi'           # sample comment`.

And I used `:%s/^\([^#]*\)\(#.*\)/\2\r    \1/gc` to change their format in vim.
By the command above, I got the result below:

```
# sample comment
    print 'hi'\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s
```

It's almost what I want, except the invisible extra whitespaces which I use `\s` to indicate in the result.

It seems the `\([^#]*\)` part of the vim command didn't include the whitespaces into its scope.

Why this happened, how to fix it?

Comment: It's actual include trailing whitespaces. You can use `:%s/^\([^#]*\)\(#.*\)/\2\r    \1A/gc` to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your first capturing group *does* include the spaces.

```
    ^\([^#]*\)\(#.*\)
    | --------  -------- the comment 
begin    | 
    everything upto #
    including spaces
```

To fix it, you want to leave the spaces out of the capturing group, like so:

```
   ^\(.\{-}\)\s*\(#.*\)
   |  ------  --   ------ comment
begin    |     \____ any amount of whitespace
  non-greedy match
```

That would make your full command:

```
%s/^\(.\{-}\)\s*\(#.*\)/\2\r    \1/gc
```

Comment: Then why `\(.*\)` doesn't work, either, which I think include whitespace?

Comment: @Zen: It *does* include whitespace, but you *don't* want it to include the trailing whitespace. `.*` is a greedy match, which means it will match the longest substring it can. `\s*` can match the empty string, and `.*` precedes it, so `.*` will end up matching everything. `.\{-}` is a non-greedy match, which means it will match the shortest substring it can, and then `\s*` will match any trailing whitespace. Because `\s*` is outside the capturing group, the spaces do not end up in the final result.

Comment: I got the whole point now, before I messed up the logics in my brain, it's my fault. Now all clear, thanks!